# How to include empty string as a group in group by in linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

i have barcode column that string type. How to group by barcode column that include empty string as group and other value are only unique.
My Table looks like below.

[image: table]

```
 productImportList.GroupBy(f => f.BarCode);//productImportList contains list of ProductImport Class Object List
var res=productImportList.GroupBy(f => f.BarCode).Select(x=>x.First());
```

its result like something this.

[image]

but i need for getting result like below.

[image]

thanks.

Comment: What is the criteria that entries need to make in order to be valid?

Comment: yes string is empty

Comment: criteria is like if barcode is duplicate then select first row as default and if barcode is empty then it consider as row.

Comment: you need to group by barcode and title to get the output you are showing

Comment: The result you have stated you want is missing a row for `ddd` which is also empty - is that just an incorrect image?

Comment: i have used Select(x=>x.First());so that it select first and ignore other barcode empty string for that ddd is missing its image is correct.

Comment: @Ljdhameliya So what is the logic then? You have 3 rows with an empty `BarCode` (`aaa`, `ddd` and `fff`) yet you want to show 2 out of the 3. And what if you have 5 rows with an empty `BarCode` - which of those would you want to display?

Comment: yes sorry is that ddd is in image i will edit.thanks,i will edit

Comment: And does the order matter - is it acceptable to have all items with no `BarCode` listed first (or last) followed by the grouped items?

Comment: does not order matter.yes you got my point have all item with no barcode and select first when barcode is duplicate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128246/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ljdhameliya).

Answer (score 3):

So you want each individual entry with an empty barcode to end up in the result. A trick could be to make the empty entries unique in the grouping:

```
productImportList.GroupBy(f => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.Barcode)
                                  ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() 
                                  : f.Barcode )
                 .Select(x=>x.First())
```

Result:

```
Barcode title
10  abc
    aaa
15  bbb
20  ccc
    ddd
    fff
24  ggg
48  hhh
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var res=productImportList.GroupBy(f => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.BarCode) ? String.Empty : f.BarCode).Select(x=>x.First());
```

That will make sure that all kind of values, `null`, empty strings and all white space strings are treated alike.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment that the order does not matter, create 2 queries based on the value of `BarCode()` and then concatenate them.

```
var productImportList = ... // your query to get all data
// get all records with no BarCode
var noBC = productImportList.Where(x => x.BarCode == null);
// get the first record in each BarCode group
var hasBC = productImportList.Where(x => x.BarCode != null).GroupBy(f => f.BarCode).Select(x=>x.First());
// concatenate the queries
var result = noBC.Concat(hasBC);
```

Note the above assumes the no `BarCode` means its `null` (if its actually an empty string, then you can use `.Equals(String.Empty)`)

Comment: but if productimportList contains lots of data and we execute two query it is feasible for performance. in my website sometime ProductImportList contains 1 million data some times.

Comment: Only you can test that, and you will probably want to index the `BarCode` field

Comment: But why would you ever be returning a million rows anyway - you cannot possible be using that much data in a view.

Comment: its all rows come from url in json format and converted into list and need to store in database.means like import functionality from url json and xml data